# How do I change value of a boolean field on a node when a user clicks a button?

Tags: entities, nodes, rules

I am building a small site for a friend who is getting married and they have their gift list online. Each gift is a node which I am thinking will have a boolean field called something like "bought". The functionality I want to create is that visitors can look at a list of gifts and, if they want to buy something for them they just need to click a button next to it.

So my question is simple, can I change the value of a node field when a user clicks a button?

Comment: if this is the exact use case, and you don't want to use the contrib module Wishlist mentioned by @molot, this sounds like a great use of the status field already there, eg, upon purchase, unpublish the node.

Answer (score 1):

There is a ready contrib module: [Wishlist](http://drupal.org/project/wishlist).

> Other site users can indicate their interest in purchasing an item from a wishlist. When that happens, everybody can see that somebody purchased the item and duplicated gifts are eliminated (or reduced - the wishlist module does rely on people playing nicely together).

If you just want the job done, that's your way to go. If you want to learn, read about [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) and [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).